Banner Component Overlapping Hero Section in Next.js Layout
I'm working on a Next.js project and facing an issue where my Banner component is overlapping with the Hero component. Here's the structure of my components and layout:
Screenshot of the issue
Home Page (page.tsx)
/** @format */

import Hero from "@/components/hero/hero";
import Banner from "@/components/banner/banner";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Hero />
            <Banner />
        </>
    );
}


Root Layout (layout.tsx)
/** @format */

import Navbar from "@/components/navbar/navbar";
import "./global.css";

export const metadata = {
    title: "Next.js",
    description: "Generated by Next.js",
};

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Navbar />
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}


Navbar Component (navbar.tsx)
/** @format */
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faFacebook, faYoutube } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

const Navbar = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center my-6 md:mb-8">
            <div className="flex items-center max-sm:flex-col md:ml-12 md:mx-4 md:flex-row xl:ml-16 xl:mx-8 text-center justify-center">
                <div className="p-1 mr-4">
                    <Image
                        src="/logoMin.png"
                        alt="Sarvodaya Higher Secondary School Logo"
                        width={100}
                        height={100}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-between md:flex-row flex-col px-8 items-center ">
                    <div>
                        <h1 className="heading-text-red font-black text-[30px] text-center md:text-start">
                            SARVODAYA ENGLISH HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL LAKHNADON{" "}
                        </h1>
                        <h3 className="heading-text-yellow font-black text-center md:text-start">
                            A Commitment to Best Education and Discipline for a Better World
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="heading-text-red font-black flex gap-3 ml-10 md:mb-10 justify-between m-4 items-center">
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@sarvodayaschoollakhnadon">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} size="2x" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mangal.vishwakarma.7545708">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} size="2x" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" flex justify-between p-4 w-full bg-red-500 text-white md:hidden">
                    <a href="/admission">Get Admission</a>
                    <div className="justify-end items-center text-white md:hidden">
                        <button onClick={toggleMenu}>MENU</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                className={`flex flex-col items-center backdrop-blur-sm bg-red-500/10 md:hidden ${
                    isOpen ? "" : "hidden"
                }`}
            >
                <a href="/" className="text-white my-2">
                    Home
                </a>
                <a href="/about" className="text-white my-2">
                    About
                </a>
                <a href="/contact" className="text-white my-2">
                    Contact
                </a>
                <a href="/services" className="text-white my-2">
                    Services
                </a>
                <a href="/blog" className="text-white my-2">
                    Blog
                </a>
                <a href="/faq" className="text-white my-2">
                    FAQ
                </a>
                <a href="/gallery" className="text-white my-2">
                    Gallery
                </a>
                <a href="/admission" className="text-white my-2">
                    Get Admission
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
                <div className="flex w-[90%] justify-between backdrop-blur-sm bg-red-500/10 ">
                    <div className="p-6  justify-center hidden md:flex">
                        <a href="/" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            Home
                        </a>
                        <a href="/about" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            About
                        </a>
                        <a href="/contact" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            Contact
                        </a>
                        <a href="/services" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            Services
                        </a>
                        <a href="/blog" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            Blog
                        </a>
                        <a href="/faq" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            FAQ
                        </a>
                        <a href="/gallery" className="ml-4 text-white">
                            Gallery
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className="p-6 text-white font-black bg-red-500 hidden md:block"
                        style={{ clipPath: "polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)" }}
                    >
                        <a href="/admission">Get Admission</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-center md:my-1">
                {" "}
                <div className=" marquee p-4 heading-text-red text-xl font-black flex md:w-[90%] justify-between backdrop-blur-sm  bg-white/30">
                    <div className="marquee-content">
                        Teacher Requirement 2024-25 Subject-
                        Maths/Bio/Physics/Chemistry/Sanskrit/Sociology/Commerce/Hindi/English
                        | From Class 6th to 12th | Starting Salary From Rs. 20000/- to Rs.
                        25000/- |Contact:+91 8989646850
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;


Hero Component (hero.tsx)
/** @format */

import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const Hero = () => {
    const quickLinks = [
        {
            heading: "Get Admission Now for session 2024-25",
            link: "/admission",
            info: "Secure your spot for the upcoming academic year.",
        },
        {
            heading: "Result for session 2023-24 is out now",
            link: "/result",
            info: "Check your results for the past academic year.",
        },
        {
            heading: "Teacher Recruitment for session 2024-25",
            link: "/careers",
            info: "Join our team for the next academic session.",
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center my-8 ">
            <Image
                className="absolute inset-0 w-full object-cover z-[-1]"
                src="/bg.webp"
                alt="School Building"
                layout="fill"
            />
            <div className="w-[90%] absolute md:flex justify-center items-center sm:flex-col md:flex-row">
                <div className="md:w-[60%]">
                    <h1 className="heading-text-yellow text-4xl font-black sm:mb-2 md:mb-8">
                        WELCOME TO SARVODAYA ENGLISH HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL
                    </h1>
                    <p className="heading-text-red text-3xl md:text-6xl sm:mb-4 md:mb-8">
                        Best Education & Discipline Expertise
                    </p>
                    <p className="heading-text-white my-8 text-xl font-bold hidden md:block">
                        Discipline is an essential component of education, as it helps
                        students develop self-control, focus, and responsibility, which are
                        crucial skills for achieving academic success and becoming lifelong
                        learners.
                    </p>
                    <button className="bg-red-500 text-white mt-4 mr-4 p-4 rounded-md md:w-60">
                        Get Admission Now
                    </button>
                    <button className="bg-white text-red-500 mt-4 mr-4 p-4 rounded-md md:w-60">
                        Visit Campus
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center md:w-[40%] mt-4 md:mt-0">
                    <div className="flex flex-col w-full mt-8 md:backdrop-blur-sm bg-yellow-500/10 p-4 rounded-md">
                        <h2 className="text-red-500 text-center text-2xl font-bold mb-4">
                            Quick Links
                        </h2>
                        <div className="flex flex-col items-center max-h-80 overflow-y-auto scrollbar-hide">
                            {quickLinks.map((link, index) => (
                                <a
                                    key={index}
                                    href={link.link}
                                    className="text-white my-2 w-full px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 rounded-md hover:bg-red-600 transition-colors"
                                >
                                    <h3 className="font-semibold">{link.heading}</h3>
                                    <p className="text-sm">{link.info}</p>
                                </a>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Hero;


Banner Component (banner.tsx)
/** @format */

import React from "react";

const Banner = () => {
    const bannerData = [
        {
            cover: "https://img.icons8.com/external-yogi-aprelliyanto-basic-outline-yogi-aprelliyanto/80/ffffff/external-graduation-education-yogi-aprelliyanto-basic-outline-yogi-aprelliyanto.png",
            data: "700+",
            title: "STUDENTS",
        },
        {
            cover: "https://img.icons8.com/ios/80/ffffff/athlete.png",
            data: "30+",
            title: "TRAINED TEACHER",
        },
        {
            cover: "https://img.icons8.com/external-outline-icons-maxicons/80/ffffff/external-calender-insurance-outline-outline-icons-maxicons.png",
            data: "99%",
            title: "RESULT",
        },
        {
            cover: "https://img.icons8.com/ios/80/ffffff/macbook-idea--v3.png",
            data: "STREAMS",
            title: "SCIENCE & COMMERCE",
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="flex relative justify-center">
            {bannerData.map((val, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="flex items-center justify-between mb-8">
                    <div className="w-1/2 mr-4">
                        <img src={val.cover} alt="" className="w-full rounded-lg" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-1/2">
                        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{val.data}</h1>
                        <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold">{val.title}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Banner;


The Banner component overlaps the Hero section, causing a layout issue. I've tried various CSS adjustments but can't seem to resolve the overlap problem. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the Banner component correctly appears below the Hero section?

Can you add a screenshot showing the problem?
